# EditText Integer_Input_Type crashes when null

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext, integer

To avoid unnecessary stuff, the **validate** function is called when the update, delete, insert button are clicked. The problem is with the `EditText` with `inputType="number"` i.e with etPrice and etSNumber.I think,there is something wrong with the `validate_price()` and `validate_supplier_no()`.Please Correct Me.

```
public class QueryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText etName, etPrice, etSupplier, etSNumber;
        private Button insert_btn, increment, decrement, update_btn, delete_btn, call_btn;
        private TextView quantity_tv;
        private int quantity_value = 0;
        private TextInputLayout inputLayout_name, inputLayout_price, inputLayout_supplier, inputLayout_supplier_no;
        int _id, price, quantity, supplier_no = 0;
        String name, supplier;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_query);

            increment = findViewById(R.id.increment);
            decrement = findViewById(R.id.decrement);
            insert_btn = findViewById(R.id.insert_btn);
            update_btn = findViewById(R.id.update_product);
            delete_btn = findViewById(R.id.delete_product);
            call_btn = findViewById(R.id.call_btn);

            etName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
            etPrice = findViewById(R.id.et_price);
            quantity_tv = findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            etSupplier = findViewById(R.id.et_supplier);
            etSNumber = findViewById(R.id.et_sNumber);


            inputLayout_name = findViewById(R.id.textInput_name);
            inputLayout_price = findViewById(R.id.textInput_price);
            inputLayout_supplier = findViewById(R.id.textInput_supplier);
            inputLayout_supplier_no = findViewById(R.id.textInput_supplier_no);


            Intent intent = getIntent();
            _id = intent.getIntExtra("_id", 0);
            name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
            price = intent.getIntExtra("price", 0);
            quantity = intent.getIntExtra("quantity", 0);
            quantity_value = quantity;
            supplier = intent.getStringExtra("supplier");
            supplier_no = intent.getIntExtra("supplier_no", 0);

            String price_str = String.valueOf(price);

            if (_id != 0) {
                etName.setText(name.toString());
                etPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
                quantity_tv.setText(String.valueOf(quantity).toString());
                etSupplier.setText(supplier.toString());
                etSNumber.setText(String.valueOf(supplier_no));
                insert_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                update_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                delete_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            //OnClickListeners
            insert_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    validate(v);
                    insertProduct();
                }
            });
            update_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    validate(v);
                    updateProduct();
                }
            });
            delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    validate(v);
                    deleteProduct();
                }
            });

            //add quantity btn
            increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quantity_value += 1;
                    display(quantity_value);
                }
            });

            //subtract quantity btn
            decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quantity_value -= 1;
                    if (quantity_value <= -1) {
                        quantity_value = 0;
                    }
                    display(quantity_value);
                }
            });

            call_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(supplier_no==0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Supplier Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Intent intent_call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", String.valueOf(supplier_no), null));
                        startActivity(intent_call);
                    }
                }
            });


        }//onCreate Ends


        public void validate(View view) {
           try {
               if (validate_name() && validate_price() && validate_supplier() && validate_supplier_no()) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException e){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }


        }
        private boolean validate_supplier_no() {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etSNumber.getText().toString())) {
            inputLayout_supplier_no.setError("Invalid input");
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayout_supplier_no.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

        private boolean validate_supplier() {

            if (etSupplier.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                inputLayout_supplier.setError("Supplier cannot be blanked");
                return false;
            } else {
                inputLayout_supplier.setErrorEnabled(false);
                return true;
            }
        }

        private boolean validate_price() {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPrice.getText().toString())) {
                inputLayout_price.setError("Invalid input");
                return false;
            } else {
                inputLayout_price.setErrorEnabled(false);
                return true;
            }
        }

        private boolean validate_name() {
            if (etName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                inputLayout_name.setError("Name cannot be blanked");
                return false;
            } else {
                inputLayout_name.setErrorEnabled(false);
                return true;
            }
        }


        private void deleteProduct() {

            String selection = _ID + " = ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(_id)};

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, _id);
            int rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }

        private void updateProduct() {

            String selection = _ID + " = ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(_id)};

            String et_productName = etName.getText().toString();
            int et_productPrice = Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString());
            int tv_productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_tv.getText().toString());
            String et_productSupplier = etSupplier.getText().toString();
            int et_productSNumber = Integer.parseInt(etSNumber.getText().toString());

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, et_productName);
            values.put(PRICE, et_productPrice);
            values.put(QUANTITY, tv_productQuantity);
            values.put(SUPPLIER, et_productSupplier);
            values.put(SUPPLIER_NO, et_productSNumber);


            Uri uri = CONTENT_URI;
            int rowsUpdated = getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item inserted at: " + rowsUpdated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


        private void insertProduct() {

            String et_productName = etName.getText().toString();
            int et_productPrice = Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString());
            int tv_productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_tv.getText().toString());
            String et_productSupplier = etSupplier.getText().toString();
            int et_productSNumber = Integer.parseInt(etSNumber.getText().toString());

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, et_productName);
            values.put(PRICE, et_productPrice);
            values.put(QUANTITY, tv_productQuantity);
            values.put(SUPPLIER, et_productSupplier);
            values.put(SUPPLIER_NO, et_productSNumber);

            Uri uri = CONTENT_URI;
            Uri uriRowsInserted = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item inserted at: " + uriRowsInserted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //for updating the quantity_tv
        public void display(int number) {
            quantity_tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".QueryActivity"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Product Name..."
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Product Price..."
            android:inputType="number" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increment"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrement"
            android:layout_width="55dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput_supplier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_supplier"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Supplier Name..."
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput_supplier_no"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_sNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter SupplierNumber..."
            android:inputType="number" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/insert_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:text="ADD IT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_product"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:text="DELETE IT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/update_product"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:text="Save Changes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/call_btn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/call"
            android:drawablePadding="-40dp"
            android:text="CALL" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** With Empty etPrice or etSNumber,this code throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`

Comment: Please post your full code, it is not sufficient to understand your problem, please post your xml file and code both so that we can understand your problem more nicely.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: `int et_productPrice = Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString());
int et_productSNumber = Integer.parseInt(etSNumber.getText().toString());` are you getting exception over here ?

Comment: No! It's happening in the validate method i.e the price and SNumber validation methods. As we leave either of these two empty(etPrice and etSNumber),CRASH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call insertProduct, deleteProduct and updateProduct only if inputs are valid. Change your method validate like below

```
public boolean validate(View view) {
       try {
           if (validate_name() && validate_price() && validate_supplier() && validate_supplier_no()) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return true;
           }
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       return false;
    }
```

and start using as

```
       delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(validate(v)) {
                    deleteProduct();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I do completely understand, but to post as a comment minimum reputation score should be 50, but unfortunately I don't have that for now. will take care of it now onward. thanks

Comment: I added everything...please help me solve this query

Comment: The problem is not to check if its numeric,the problem is to check if its EMPTY or NOT.

Comment: Crash is obvious, we just have to avoid that. why you don't check empty before parsing

Comment: That's what I am trying to do the whole time! But the inputType="number" is making things go wrong.

Comment: @RatooRaj see the edited answer, that should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

you can Set Error for your EditText not for your Layout.So you car rewrite your code by this way:

```
 etPrice.setError ("Price cannot be blanked");
  return false;
  } else {
  etPrice.setErrorEnabled(false);
  return true;
```